# Can't filter 'reports/product_collection' on category

Tags: magento-1.8, product, reports

What I'm basically trying to do is sort a product collection by sales so that the most sold product is on top.

Since there doesn't seem to be a standard way to do this in Magento, I first want to get the product ID's of the most sold products by category, like this;

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load({category_id});
$reports = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                 ->addOrderedQty()
                 ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
```

After which I will do some magic with these ID's and create my products JSON.
However, first I'd have to filter the reports per category, but the stock `addCategoryFilter()` function doesn't work. If I try to do a `->getSelect()` after applying the category filter, and search for something like 'category', I find nothing. The function `addCategoryFilter()` doesn't seem to do anything.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I know that would work with catalog/product_collection, but not so sure about reports, have you checked the table in the DB to be sure that category and ordered_qty are available?
Btw, to make a `getSelect()` work, you should do as follow : `$myCollection->count(); echo $mycollection->getSelect()->__toString();`

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the getSelect tip, I now see that it does include category in the query. I know for a fact that `ordered_qty` is available, I see it being returned. With the SQL query I will be able to tweak this further, thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Haha wow. If I only add `$reports->count();` to my test code, it suddenly works! If I leave it out, it doesn't. Do you have a clue why? The rest of my code is simply doing `$reports->getData()` in a foreach loop.

Comment: for some reasons beyond my comprehension (and because I didn't really look into Magento's core), when you `getSelect` on a collection without `count`'ing first, then the `setOrder` won't be visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try building your reports like this:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load({category_id});
$reports = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->addOrderedQty()
             ->addCategoryFilter($category)
             ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
```

I mean use `addCategoryFilter` after `addOrderQty`. in the method `addOrderQty` there is this line `$this->getSelect()->reset()` that seams to remove your category filter.

Comment: for single category code is working fine, I have tried addAttributeToFilter('category_ids',array('finset'=>'{categor1},{category2}')) but it is not working please suggest for multiple categories filter

Comment: I don't think It's possible for 2 categories.

Comment: can we filter this using a product attribute value

Comment: Not sure. I wrote this 4+ years ago. BUt you can try with `addAttributeToFilter`

Answer (score 0):

**Using custom query : Get the bestselling product from last 15 days with multiple categories**

```
$startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(' - 15 days'));
$endDate = date('Y-m-d');
$categories = "{{Category1}},{{category2}},{{category3}}";
// example $categories = "5,6,7";           

$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "SELECT Sum(order_items.qty_ordered) AS `ordered_qty`, 
       `order_items`.`name`         AS `order_items_name`, 
       `order_items`.`product_id`   AS `entity_id`, 
       `e`.`entity_type_id`, 
       `e`.`attribute_set_id`, 
       `e`.`type_id`, 
       `e`.`sku`, 
       `e`.`has_options`, 
       `e`.`required_options`, 
       `e`.`created_at`, 
       `e`.`updated_at`, 
       `cat_index`.`position`       AS `cat_index_position`,
       `stock_table`.`qty`          AS `quantity`
FROM   `sales_flat_order_item` AS `order_items` 
       INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `order` 
               ON `order`.entity_id = order_items.order_id 
                  AND `order`.state <> 'canceled' 
                  AND ( `order`.created_at BETWEEN '".$startDate."' AND '".$endDate."' 
                      ) 
       LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
              ON ( e.type_id NOT IN ( 'grouped', 'configurable', 'bundle' ) ) 
                 AND e.entity_id = order_items.product_id 
                 AND e.entity_type_id = 4 
       INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` 
               ON cat_index.product_id = e.entity_id 
                  AND cat_index.store_id = '1' 
                  AND cat_index.visibility IN( 2, 4 ) 
                  AND cat_index.category_id IN(".$categories.")
       INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `stock_table`
               ON stock_table.product_id = e.entity_id  
WHERE  ( parent_item_id IS NULL ) AND stock_table.qty > 0  
GROUP  BY `order_items`.`product_id` 
HAVING ( Sum(order_items.qty_ordered) > 0 ) 
ORDER  BY RAND() 
LIMIT  6"; 
$orderCollection = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

Hope this will help someone!